# How to get an upright \partial?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, kpfonts

I want to set partial derivations like `\frac{\partial}{\partial x}`. This is issue is discussed several times here. Packages like esdiff or commath or suggested. However one problem with all those solutions is that the `\partial` is not set upright. Usually a recommendation is to use  `kpfonts` or other fonts. Assume I do not want to change my font. Is there some LaTeX command to set the `\partial` upright or is this always a font issue? I have tried using `\mathrm`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211060/sans-serif-partial-derivative-symbol/211127#211127

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\usepackage[partialup]{kpfonts}
```

or if you do *not* want to load the kpfonts:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifkp@upRm% is used in the .fd-file of jkp
\DeclareSymbolFont{Letters}{OML}{jkp}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partialup}{\mathord}{Letters}{128}
\makeatother
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{\partialup f}{\partialup x} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get upright partial symbol in Computer Modern the following way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
    \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
    \hskip\wd\foobox
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
    \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
    \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\newcommand{\uppartial}{\unslant\partial}
\newcommand{\upPartial}{\unslant\partial\kern-0.8pt}


\begin{document}

\[\bm{E} = -\left( \frac{\uppartial  V}{\uppartial x} \bm{\hat{\imath}} +                 \frac{\uppartial V}{\uppartial y}\bm{\hat{\jmath}} + \frac{\uppartial V}    {\uppartial z}\bm{\hat{k}} \right)\]\\

\[\bm{E} = -\left( \frac{\upPartial  V}{\upPartial x} \bm{\hat{\imath}} +     \frac{\upPartial V}{\upPartial y}\bm{\hat{\jmath}} + \frac{\upPartial V}{\upPartial z}\bm{\hat{k}} \right)\]\\

\[\bm{E} = -\left( \frac{\partial  V}{\partial x} \bm{\hat{\imath}} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\bm{\hat{\jmath}} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\bm{\hat{k}} \right)\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Partial Symbols]

This is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230220/128462).

Edit:

The newtx package offers an `\uppartial` option, which can be used to get upright partials matching different fonts, such as Times, Libertinus, Fourier, Charter, Stix2, etc.

If one is fine with using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then almost all math fonts which support Unicode math have the glyph, including Latin Modern and New Computer Modern (Computer Modern clones). You can pass the option `partial=upright` while loading the `unicode-math` package as `\usepackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}` or use `\PassOptionsToPackage{partial=upright}{unicode-math}` if `unicode-math` is loaded by some other package later. There are other partial symbols defined in the Unicode standard as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{partial=upright}{unicode-math}
\usepackage[default, newcmbb]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \(\partial\)
\end{document}
```

[image: upright partial new computer modern newcm]

Comment: May be a `\reflectbox{$6$}` would work as an upright partial?

Comment: Not terrible, but I see that it looks better with this “unslant partial symbol”.

Comment: @Manuel My choice of words was poor. This symbol looks fatter.

Comment: @Manuel Also, the size of reflected 6 does not match with other characters in inline mode.

Answer (score 4):

Another nice approach could be rotating and scaling the `\partial` symbol by this one-liner:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\uppartial}{\text{\rotatebox[origin=t]{20}{\scalebox{0.95}[1]{$\partial$}}}\hspace{-1pt}}
```

It uses the normal partial symbol, squeezes it a bit horizontally, rotates it around the top for 20 deg and minimizes the distance to the following symbol.

Now you can use `\uppartial` in your math environment and get nice results like this:

[image: uppartial]

**For Germans:** DIN 1338 regulates which symbols are written in italics and which ones upright (see [de:Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsatz#Geradestehende.2C_geneigte_und_kursive_Schrift))