# Partial derivative symbol style

Tags: fonts

I'm using standard template and I'm getting the following partial derivative operator in the left of picture below.

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{equation*}
   \partial
   \end{equation*}
   \end{document}
```

I would like to know how to obtain the partial derivative operator in the right. Are there other font styles for this symbol?

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W32Xa.png) are partials from some fonts.

Comment: Do you know how to put this style specifically?

Comment: Sorry, no, I think these were the math fonts I had available. If you have a pdf file with this partial symbol, you might get a clue by looking at what fonts are in there.

Comment: how did you make the image in your question, if that was from an electronic document you can probably query the font

Answer (score 4):

Compiling with XeLaTeX engine the desidered symbol have a name: **Unicode Character “∂” (U+2202)**. Remembering that this symbol lie on font Times New Roman you will obtain the partial derivative operator in the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\frac{∂^2f}{∂^2x^2}+ \frac{∂^2f}{∂^2y^2} +\frac{∂^2f}{∂^2z^2}=0$
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[\scaleobj{5}{\partial \to} \scaleobj{5}{∂}\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: \partial = ∂.

Comment: However, since the symbol of partial derivative is not a variable, it is officially (according to standards) correct to write it upright (not curly). Is it possible to do this, maybe just changing the font of it?

Comment: @umby I have understood what you are asking but I cannot give you an answer. Click on the **Ask question** button. Greetings.

Comment: Sebastiano, thanks a lot, but I found a good solution for me at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170567/273692.